# Azure APP Service Application Log not working

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App for a .net core API, which in turn has a Sub Application (Virtual Directory). I have enabled Application log in the Diagnostic setting in the Azure Portal. I had done this for a another service and worked fine. When I have the services with multiple Virtual Directory setup it fails. Do we need any extra code in the Configure section if we have this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue you mentioned. It works well to get Application logs. I also created a Virtual Directory in App Service. (refer to this  [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/)). And we needn’t to add extra code. You could follow my steps.

In Azure portal>APP Service>Application settings(create virtual directory ‘janley’):

[image]

Code in application: (Add the trace info).

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("my trace info Home/Index");
            return View();
        }
public ActionResult About()
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("my trace info Home/About");

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("my trace info Home/Contact");

            return View();
        }
```

You could see the logs in KuDu like this:
[image]

Besides, for more details about how to trace and view the application logs, you could read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the app from .net core to .net framework worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following extension is installed on ur app service. After installing this extension it worked for me.

To access the Kudu console goto ur app service in azure > advanced > launch Kudu

[image: kudu console with log extension]